# Bundler::GemRequireError when adding gem

Tags: react.rb

When I make a new Rails project, add `gem 'reactive-record'`, and run `rails server`, I get a Bundler error: `There was an error while trying to load the gem 'reactive-record'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)`.

What gives? I have Rails 4.2.5 and Ruby 2.1.2.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the generator should work very well with the help of Mitch. We collaborated together to make a generator in order to simplify greatly the installation of react.rb and reactive-record.

You should be able to get up and running by adding to your gem file :
gem 'reactive_rails_generator'

Then do a `bundle install`

and finally :

`rails g reactrb:install --all
bundle update`

Will install you reactrb, reactive-record and reactive-router.
Once installed, you can create components by doing : 
`rails g reactrb:component Home::Show`

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the problem like this:

1. Set rvm to use Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.4.
2. Download `https://codeload.github.com/catprintlabs/reactive-record/zip/master`
3. Edited `reactive-record-master/Gemfile` to read:

   ```
   gem 'reactive-ruby'
   gem 'opal'
   gem 'opal-browser'
   gem 'react-rails'
   ```
4. `cd reactive-record-master/spec/test_app`
5. `bundle install`
6. `rails server`

This seemed to work.

Then, I made a new Rails 4.2.4 project. Adding only `gem 'reactive-record'` to the Gemfile resulted in the same error. Then I made the Gemfile read:

```
gem 'reactive-ruby'
gem 'opal'
gem 'opal-browser'
gem 'react-rails'
gem 'reactive-record'
```

And *voila*, `rails server` works!

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Jamie - thanks a lot... fyi there should be a rails generator for react.rb and reactive-record out there shortly.  We will be sure to incorporate your suggestion to make sure it all works.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn Oh gosh I would love a generator :) I'm still having trouble getting my full stack going and will be posting another question here shortly... that would be resolved if a generator existed.

Comment: Okay well hopefully we should have something up for you to try in under an hour...check in https://gitter.im/zetachang/react.rb I will post any updates there first

Comment: see my answer below... a preliminary version is working and available.